# How do I add multiple animators to my character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have my main character and added a capsule collider 2d so he would take damage when attacked. When the character is attacking, for example his body is out of the collider space and won’t take damage when hit. Please may you help me solve this issue, I’m very new to unity

Comment: Surely, you're asking about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is having two different hitboxes that does the same thing but with different shapes so they match two different states of your character.

Enable and disable them in a script when calling the attack using:

```
 Public Collider2D attackCollider; //Drag your attack collider here in the inspector
 Public Collider2D idleCollider; //Drag your idle collider here in the inspector

 void AttackCollider() //call this fucntion to change to attack collider
 {
 attackCollider.enabled == true;
 idleCollider.enabled == false;
 }

 void IdleCollider() //call this function to go back to normal collider.
 {
 attackCollider.enabled == false;
 idleCollider.enabled == true;
 }
```

If you want to I'm sure you can incorporate these two functions into an already existing attack function if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

- In 3D, you could simply make the Collider a child of any of your bones, it would get animated altogether.

But you mentioned Collider2D, so:

- If you have a 2D Rig with bones, you can do the same as obove
- If you have a Keyframe Animation, you could animate the collider to match your animation